# AWS S3 - Access denied when getting bucket location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket called "my-bucket" in account A and I'm trying to determine it's location from account B.

I have the following bucket policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11122233344:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11122233344:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    }
]}
```

I've also stumbled across this documentation which contains the same policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Now using account B, I can successfully execute the command `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`, however with `aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket my-bucket` I get the access denied message.

Comment: The *user* in Account 2 needs an IAM user policy granting this permission against the foreign bucket.  What you have done so far is to allow such a grant to be honored, if it exists.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, the user in account 2 has been allowed all s3 actions on any resource.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html

> To use this implementation of the operation, you must be the bucket
>   owner.

When in doubt always refer to the AWS API documentation it usually specifies the permission needed for the given action.

Comment: The one line I missed.. However I could get the bucket location when I use the CLI with the profile set to account B, it seems odd

Comment: @petrch the documentation is not correct.  I just modified a test bucket to grant `s3:GetBucketLocation` to `"Principal": "*"` and was able to get the bucket location anonymously.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot interesting, the Principal account number I could not check because of course you used a placeholder. Probably this should be interpreted as "the backet owner or a role which assumed the owners role". That does make sense.